# Convert Sql Query to Laravel Query

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I'm having trouble converting my sql to Laravel Query.

```
$users = DB::select(DB::raw(
            'SELECT User.*, Registration_Update.created_at as lastRegistrationUpdate
            FROM User
            JOIN Registration_Update
            ON Registration_Update.user_id = User.id
            WHERE Registration_Update.created_at = (
              SELECT MAX(Registration_Update.created_at)
              FROM Registration_Update
              WHERE User.id = Registration_Update.user_id
            )
            AND Registration_Update.deleted_at IS NULL'
    ));
```

Comment: have you tried to use `join()` Helper method of laravel?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with code:

```
$result = DB::table('User as U')
        ->join('Registration_Update as RU', 'RU.user_id', '=', 'U.id')
        ->select('U.*', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(MAX(RU.created_at),'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') as lastRegistrationUpdate"))
        ->whereNull('RU.deleted_at')
        ->groupBy('U.id')
        ->get();
```